# How to import select objects from various modules into __init__.py?

Tags: python, import

Given the following package:

```
package/
|
|_ __init__.py
|
|_module1.py
|  |_c1   # c1 is a string
|  |_foo  # foo is a function
|  |_bar  # bar is a function
|  |_exports = (c1, foo)  # or maybe ('c1', 'foo') ?
|
|_module2.py
   |_c2  # c2 is a string
   |_c3  # c3 is a float
   |_exports = (c2,)  # or maybe ('c2',) ?
```

I want to import `c1`, `foo`, and `c2` into `__init__.py`. The obvious way is to explicitly write the imports inside `__init__.py`:

```
from module1 import c1, foo
from module2 import c2
```

Now I could write source such as:

```
import package
print(package.c1)
```

My goal, however, is to use the registry lists `exports`. I tried using `importlib` within `__init__.py` but got nowhere :(

Any help is preciously considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `__all__` in the python file.  It is a list of strings defining what symbols in a module will be exported when `from <module> import *` is used on the module.

in python file under `__all__` give all the function which you want to expose to outside .

eg is in `module1.py` write `__all__ = ['c1','foo']` and in in `module2.py` write `__all__=['c2']`

then in `__init__.py` file wite

```
from .module1 import * 
from  .module2 import *
__all__ = module1.__all__ + module2.__all__
```

this is it . then you can import as `from package import foo`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this definitely works. I tried using `__all__` but clearly I hadn't understood it.
I've got some reading to do :)

Comment: @jmborr yes , you got to know more things when you read documentations